# How to Name an Array with an input

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a Grocery List that I am able to create from an array of foods.  What I am trying to do is name the array when I store it.  I have my copy hung here [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DYMi3BvTa3j3WRt4TWcs)

Currently the output looks like

```
    [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Coconuts"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peaches"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oranges"
  }
]
```

I would like it to be something like

```
    [
  {"John's List":
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Coconuts"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peaches"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oranges"
  }}
]
```

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Do you mean the items within "John's List" to be an array also?

Comment: It is possible. but you have to mention it properly. when should it happen? what should be the flow? Your plunker doesn't tell anything. Moreover, it seems incomplete too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated your save function like below

```
            $scope.save = function () {
              var entity = {};
              entity[$scope.name] = $scope.NewList;
                $scope.MyList = angular.copy(entity);
            };
```

from

```
           $scope.save = function () {
                $scope.MyList = angular.copy($scope.NewList);
            };
```

checkout this [update plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9CvCm57XwxChtoVLKYW?p=preview)

the JSON output is

```
 {
  "john's list": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Coconuts",
      "Amount": 10,
      "Price": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Peaches",
      "Amount": 5,
      "Price": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

does this matches your expected output??

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for sorry my Json wasnt accurate.  Thank you for the help.